# $\int_{-\infty}^{0}xe^{x}$ diverge or converge

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How would one find whether the following improper integral converge or diverge.

$\int_{-\infty}^{0}xe^{x}$

I did the following.

$t\rightarrow\infty$

$\int_{t}^{0}xe^x$

I did the integration by parts.

$u=x$

$dv=e^x$

$xe^x-\int 1e^x$

$xe^x-1xe^x$

$(0)(e^0)-e^0(0)-te^t-te^t$

$0-\infty-\infty$

would this mean there is a divergence.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/56628/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made an error in your integration by parts. $$xe^x-\int 1e^x=xe^x-e^x=(x-1)e^x$$

It can be shown that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}(x-1)e^x=0,$$ so the improper integral converges.

As a side note, we also have that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}xe^x=0,$$ so even if your integration by parts hadn't been erroneous, your evaluation of the limit would have been.

Comment: Hmm I did this $xe^x-1e^x$ but how would I show it converges I got    $(0)e^{0}-1e^{0}-te^t-e^t$ on one side I got $0-1-\infty-\infty$ and my right side is intermediate form.

Comment: Where would it converge to hmm if you do l hospital $\frac{e^t}{\frac{1}{t-1}}$

Comment: Rewrite as $$\frac{t-1}{e^{-t}},$$ instead. The other way only makes things worse.

Comment: Ok thanks ill try it

Comment: Incidentally, pre-limit, you should have $$0-1-te^t+e^t,$$ and in the limit as $t\to-\infty$ it becomes $$0-1-(-\infty)\cdot0+0.$$

Comment: So it is -1 convergence but I did $\frac{t-1}{e^{-t}}$ and got $1(e^{t})$ which is infinity

Comment: No, it isn't. $$\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^t=0$$

Comment: Is that because its negative infinity I see it totally forget

Comment: Yes, it is because it is $-\infty$.

Answer (score -2):

Step 1: set the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} $

Step 2: find integral (i got $xe^x - e^x$)

Step 3: plug in the limits and  ftc, so u get 
$\lim_{ t-> -\infty} [(0-e^0)-(te^t-e^t)]$

*key: $e^\infty = \infty$,
$e^-\infty = 0$

step 4: evaluate

answer: convergent sum $-1 $

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).